# How can I see what updates were installed during updating time in ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: software-center

When any notification about new updates pops out from Ubuntu Software of Ubuntu 16.04LTS but it does not shows any information regarding what updates and what their download size (in MB or GB) are being updated. Second thing,
How can a user see what packages have been updated at last time in Ubuntu Software of Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to your question can be found at [this question asked days earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765377/what-updates-is-ubuntu-software-installing).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see what packages have newer versions available and would be upgraded if you ran `dist-upgrade` or `upgrade`, try a dry-run

```
apt-get dist-upgrade --dry-run
```

you'll get some output like

> % apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade
>   NOTE: This is only a simulation!
>         apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
>         Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
>         so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Calculating upgrade...

To see what packages have been upgraded after you have run a mass upgrading, apt maintains a log of the packages you installed in

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simulate apt operation (dry-run)

Both `apt` and `apt-get` support a simulation mode via the `--dry-run` parameter.

This means you could simulate as follows

```
sudo apt upgrade --dry-run
```

or

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```

as well as for distribution upgrades

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade --dry-run
```

### Show upgradable packages (via apt list)

With `apt list` you can output a list of upgradable packages like that

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
```

### Logs: Query /var/log/dpkg.log

Regarding getting informations about changes done to a system it might be helpful to check `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

**Examples**

The entire log

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | less
```

See installed packages (new)

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install '
```

See upgrades packages

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'upgrade '
```

See removed packages

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove '
```

### Logs: Query /var/log/apt/history.log

There is a second log which contains apt informations - check `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | less
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is simply `apt list`, i.e... after performing an `apt update`, or otherwise being told that updates are available, perform the following to see them...

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
```